# can deconvolution wiener filter reduce noise without having blurred image at the first place?

Tags: python, image-processing, filter, signal-processing, wiener-filter

***Hi guys greetings***

am trying to denoise many several noises with several filters for a research i have, i found a deconvolution wiener filter made by "mr.tranleanh" on Github, as you can see [here](https://github.com/tranleanh/wiener-filter-image-restoration/blob/master/Wiener_Filter.py) .

what I did is that I canceled the blurring part in the code and only add  Gaussian noise to my images, and I made a PSNR calculation each time I apply the filter, and for each time I was increasing the size of the Gaussian kernel the PSNR value is getting bigger, so that's mean that the noise is being reduced, and all that without adding blurring to the image.

***so am wondering if I can use the wiener filter for reducing noise in this way (without blurring) i mean can a deconvolution wiener filter reduce noise without blurring?, and I also wonder why each time I apply the wiener filter the image is getting darker and darker???***

shortly this is how i typed the code :

```
def add_gaussian_noise(img, sigma):
    gauss = np.random.normal(0, sigma, np.shape(img))
    noisy_img = img + gauss
    noisy_img[noisy_img < 0] = 0
    noisy_img[noisy_img > 255] = 255
    return noisy_img
def wiener_filter(img, kernel, K):
    kernel /= np.sum(kernel)
    dummy = np.copy(img)
    dummy = fft2(dummy)
    kernel = fft2(kernel, s = img.shape)
    kernel = np.conj(kernel) / (np.abs(kernel) ** 2 + K)
    dummy = dummy * kernel
    dummy = np.abs(ifft2(dummy))
    return dummy
def gaussian_kernel(kernel_size = 3):
    h = gaussian(kernel_size, kernel_size / 3).reshape(kernel_size, 1)
    h = np.dot(h, h.transpose())
    h /= np.sum(h)
    return h
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    return np.dot(rgb[...,:3], [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Load image and convert it to gray scale
    file_name = os.path.join('/content/Hand.jpeg') 
    img = rgb2gray(plt.imread(file_name))
    # Add Gaussian noise
    noisy_img = add_gaussian_noise(blurred_img, sigma = 20)
    # Apply Wiener Filter
    kernel = gaussian_kernel(3)
    filtered_img = wiener_filter(noisy_img, kernel, K = 10)
```

***thanks in advance***

Comment: you might also want to try https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you mean I should post the same question there? can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

> Can a deconvolution wiener filter reduce noise without blurring?

This doesn't work well. If you designed a Wiener deconvolution filter for some blur kernel, yet apply it to an image that actually hasn't been blurred, then the output typically has bad looking [ringing artifacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts).

But you *can* [design a Wiener filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter) that's effective for doing just denoising, where it's assumed the input has added noise but hasn't been blurred.

> Why each time I apply the wiener filter the image is getting darker and darker???

In the Wiener deconvolution filter `np.conj(kernel) / (np.abs(kernel) ** 2 + K)`, the DC gain is `1 / (1 + K)` (noting that `kernel` is normalized to sum to one). So the output image is darker by that factor. This can be avoided by replacing the scalar `K` with something frequency-dependent like `constant * (frequency_x**2 + frequency_y**2)`.

Comment: @Pascal_Getreuer, thanks for the reply, so what are you saying is the code up there that I put in the question is not useful for denoising, and it just used to restore a blurred image, is that what are you saying ????

Comment: Yes, that's right. The Wiener deconvolution code you posted is useful for deblurring images that were blurred with `gaussian_kernel(3)`. But if Wiener deconvolution is applied to an image that actually isn't blurry in the first place, the typical effect is an output with ringing artifacts.

Comment: @Pascal_Getreuer, thanks for your reply, ohh ok now I see, the problem Is: that this is the only python code I found for the Wiener filter, and I found also this scipy.signal.wiener(), ready_function, do you think that I can use it for denoising, or its just a deconvolution filter like the previous. link  : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.wiener.html

Comment: Yes, scipy.signal.wiener does denoising. FWIW, you can try other denoising methods at [IPOL](http://www.ipol.im/). They have a couple dozen publications on image denoising (under "Topics > Enhancement & Restoration > Denoising"), which include open source reference code and demos that you can try online. For instance [here is the demo](https://ipolcore.ipol.im/demo/clientApp/demo.html?id=231) for FFDNet image denoising.